# JSF One Session Per User

Tags: java, jsf, session

I just started learning with JSF and I'm wondering about this issue.
I have 16 Checkboxes. When I open the Page and my Brother is opening it too it seems like we have the same session. When I click one of the checkboxes it is checked on my brothers browser too.
The selected checkboxes are saved in a `private ArrayList<String> selectedBoes = new ArrayList<String>();`
My ManagedBean ist SessionScoped.

Why is this happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: We need more data (and possibly, code): - Are you persisting the data somewhere (DB, File)? - When you refer to "my Brother", do you mean a different computer, or what?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I open it or another computer does. The result is the same. The selected checkboxes are saved in an `private ArrayList<String> selectedBoes = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: how do you start a session in your application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean..
I'm really new to JSF.
In the xhtml file I just have `<h:selectManyCheckbox id="selBoxes" value="#{main.selBoxes}"><f:selectItems value="#{main.boxes}"/></h:selectManyCheckbox>`

Comment: Put `<p>My session ID is #{session.id}</p>` in the page and let us know what you and your brother see.

Comment: My brothers session ID is `cdbbb126e96060ddb924b9d5e591`. Mine is `cd9a5c4180bd9dfef0ec8db2ac4d`

Answer (score 2):

> *My brothers session ID is `cdbbb126e96060ddb924b9d5e591`. Mine is `cd9a5c4180bd9dfef0ec8db2ac4d`*

Then the only possible cause is that you're *actually* not storing them in the session scope. The symptoms indicate that you're either storing them in the application scope, or even that you declared it `static` (and thus the code in the question does not represent the real code at all; the code in your comments indicate that also less or more, you used a different property name, apparently you attempted to type it from top of head, you should not do that, you should copypaste the *real* code).

Note that when you're using CDI's `@Named` instead of JSF's `@ManagedBean`, then it would default to the application scope, unless otherwise specified with a `javax.enterprise.context` scope annotation. So if you're using JSF's own `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` annotation, which is not supported by CDI, then it would still be in the application scope.

Comment: As I said I am new to JSF and I don't know how to save it session scope. The code is real. The only thing I changed is the name of the List. I declared nothing of it as static and I used @ManagedBean. For _@SessionScoped_ i used `import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`. Should I change it to `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`?

Comment: Then the problem is caused elsewhere than visible in the information provided so far. Perhaps you're simply not running the code you think you're running?

Comment: What's the difference between `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` and `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

Comment: The one is from JSF and the other is from CDI.